# Windows Console FTP - Get Username

Tags: windows, ftp, console

Is there a way to get the my username when logged into an ftp client via windows console.

Scenario: I've connected, logged in and successfully and have done a bunch of transfers/etc. I have multiple accounts on this FTP server, and forget who I am logged in as, can check that I am in the right account.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Crosspost: http://superuser.com/questions/899238/windows-console-ftp-username